# Not getting response from external web service

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm not getting a response from the external web service due to the firewall. The firewall is blocking the API request. So external API team is asking for a salesforce real IP address. So What real Salesforce real IP we need to share to them.
Please let me know and your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on which Salesforce Cloud we're talking about. In case it is Sales/Service/Community, you can refer to [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1), listing all of the IP ranges which might be of relevance. Be aware, that these depend on where your instance is located. Details on how to identify the location of your instance can be [found here.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314281&type=1&mode=1)

If it is Marketing Cloud, similar reference can be [found here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_ip_addresses_for_inclusion.htm&type=5). Also here, you well need to verify which stack you're on. This can be easily checked by looking at the URL once you're logged in.

- This domain belongs to Stack 4: https://mc.s4.exacttarget.com/
- While this one belongs to Stack 50: https://mc.s50.exacttarget.com/
- In cases where there is no definition of stack: https://mc.exacttarget.com/ then it's Stack 1.